# QToolTip show_time increase and background transparency doesn't work (PySide6)

Tags: css, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyside6

I have a `QChart` with some series. I show the `QToolTip` with current series-point after `series.hovered` event. Here is the code:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QToolTip, QLabel
from PySide6.QtGui import QCursor
from PySide6.QtCore import QPointF
from PySide6.QtCharts import QChart, QLineSeries, QChartView


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        chart_view = QChartView()

        series = QLineSeries()
        series.append(0, 0)
        series.append(1, 1)
        series.append(2, 4)
        series.append(3, 9)
        series.hovered.connect(self.show_tooltip)
        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart_view.setChart(chart)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(chart_view)

    def show_tooltip(self, point: QPointF, state):
        if state:
            text = f'{point.x()}\n{point.y()}'
            label = QLabel(text)
            label.setStyleSheet('background: rgba(255,0,0,55); border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; color: white')

            QToolTip.showText(QCursor.pos(), text, label)
        else:
            QToolTip.hideText()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    main_window = MyMainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec()
```

The problems are listed below:

- `QToolTip` does not accept opacity settings (im working on Win11).
  `QLabel` has opacity, but `QToolTip` with this label - not.
  [image]
  (Here is `rgba(255, 0, 0, 55)` color, but tooltip adds black background underneath).
- `QToolTip` hides in one second after being shown.
  `QToolTip.showText(QCursor.pos(), text, label, msecShowTime=10000)`
  doesn't help.

So, how can i solve these problems (implement real opacity and increase show time)? I don't really like overheaded solutions, because this is just a tooltip, which should not 'eat' a lot of calculating-sources.
But i will appreciate any solution.

Comment: That label is being garbage collected and it's only used partially for the generic stylesheet. You should set a proper stylesheet for the chart view using the `ToolTip` selector (which *does* support opacity). See the [Qt Style Sheet reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) and use view as target widget of the tooltip.

Comment: @musicamante, thank you for the advice. I just thought that if i'll use label, i'll override tooltip behaviour. Btw, the most interesting question it about show time. Default tooltip, can work like a pro. If i use this example `some_widget.setToolTipDuration(-1)` tooltip works pretty well and doesn't hide. But it doesn't move with cursor. So, i need to force tooltip being shown all time cursor is under the series, hide it immediately after moving cursor away from series and force it follow the cursor, like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

While the documentation reports that the widget argument of `showText()` is used to indicate the reference coordinate for the `rect` argument, it's also used as a parent for the constructor of the underlying QTipLabel (a private QLabel subclass) in case it's not being reused.

This also has the effect that any stylesheet set on the parent *can* affect the tooltip.

Your problem is that label you're creating is not persistent: it will be instantly garbage collected as soon as `show_tooltip` returns.

Some code changes between Qt5 and 6 allow to still show the tooltip (while in Qt5 it's never shown, since the widget is being destroyed), but that doesn't change the fact that that label is completely useless.

If you want to show a tooltip related to a specific widget, you *must* use that widget. In your case, it's the QChartView.

Then, if you want to set a specific style for the tool tip, you must also use proper [style sheet selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) (in general, generic properties should always be avoided).

Finally, Qt tooltips *do* support opacity; in fact, they are the *only* widget that supports the QSS [`opacity`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html#opacity-prop) property.

```py
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        # create a persistent reference to the chart view
        self.chart_view = QChartView()
        self.chart_view.setStyleSheet('''
            QToolTip {
                background: red;
                border: 1px solid #CCC;
                color: white;
                opacity: 127;
            }
        ''')
        ...

    def show_tooltip(self, point: QPointF, state):
        if state:
            QToolTip.showText(
                QCursor.pos(),
                f'{point.x()}\n{point.y()}',
                self.chart_view,
                msecShowTime=10000
            )
        else:
            QToolTip.hideText()
```

Note that:

- you should use the opacity value with care: fancy effects on informative widgets should never prevent their effectiveness; avoid setting an opacity level less than 210-220;
- the drop shadow will probably still be shown, and this cannot be worked around so easily: one possibility is to create a subclass for the chart view, watch for polish events in `childEvent()` checking for QLabel widgets with the `ToolTip` window flag, and add the `Qt.NoDropShadowWindowHint` window flag to it if it's not set;

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! 
But, after tests on Window 11 it appeared that stylesheet still exists. It works the same, as in my example. The foreground becomes transparent, but background is still black.

Comment: If you applied the exact modifications of my example code, there's no *other* stylesheet involved except for the one declared for the chart view. It seems like you're confusing what you call the "foreground" with the actual *background* of the tooltip, and the "background" with the shadow. If what you see is *the shadow*, then the last point of my answer applies: drop shadows are drawn by the system, and therefore must be disabled for each specific widget.

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same as in the screenshot in the question and it doesn't look like a shadow :(.

Comment: The question shows a *red opaque* background color with a dark gray shadow, while in the comment above you're saying a very different thing. Please be more accurate and eventually provide screenshots.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstandings. I don't really understand my first comment for now. So, about color - `rgba(255,0,0,55)` (according to your example), should be pure red color with opacity. But, we see dark red color with shadow on my screenshot (and it looks 100% similar after testing your example). If we look closely, this dark color caused by black background, not by shadow It's because red rectangle has the same dark color along its entire length. If it was a shadow darkness, we should see red half-transparent top-left corner (bc of shadow shift to right-bottom corner). But we don't.

Comment: @Mika Ok, I think I understand what you're trying to say: you're referring to the background "under" the tooltip, on which the tooltip tries to paint the semi transparent red. I probably messed up things while editing, as the background should not have an alpha value (it's a bit pointless, as we are already setting the opacity). Change that to plain `red`, and also try adding `border-radius: 0;` in case you get further issues.